# ssh keys on open shift for multiple projects from same machine

Tags: ssh, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am new to open shift .

I created a project on openshift with a new email id and password. Lets call it firstApp .  I did 
rhc setup and my ssh key was associated with my project .

My friend has also created a new project . Lets call it friendFirstApp . He wanted to give me access. 
first he shared me his user id and password . I was **unable** to login into project via

```
ssh  <long integer>@abc.rhcloud.com
```

as it says you need to set up ssh first .  Hence  I did

```
rhc setup
```

but it always goes into my firstApp project without asking me if i need to setup for a different project  ie here i needed for friendFirstApp instead of   firstApp .

my question 
1) Can i setup  rhc setup for multiple projects from same coputer 
2) is it possible for me and my friend to have  different username and passwords and still access the same application ?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend needs to share the domain with you, then you can access applications that are yours, or your friends.  Click on the "domain" that you want to share, and then click on "edit members" on the right, there you can add each others usernames and share the domain.  You can not do that with an individual application though.